# in my calculator app i have introduced four buttons but when i click them before entering values app crashes down. how to solve this problem

Tags: android, button, crash, click, calculator

```
Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            float firstValue , secondValue , ans ;

            firstValue = Float.parseFloat( etFirstValue.getText().toString());

            secondValue = Float.parseFloat( etSecondValue.getText().toString());

            ans = firstValue + secondValue;

            tvAnswer.setText("Ans = " + ans);

        }

    });
```

this is the coding for my addition button click, all buttons are working fine after entering values. but the problem occurs when I click the button before entering values my app suddenly stops working. solve this issue, make it something like nothing happens when I click the button before entering values.

Answer (score 1):

Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            float firstValue=0 , secondValue=0 , ans=0 ;

            if (etFirstValue.length()>0&& (etSecondValue.length()>0)  
           {

                firstValue = Float.parseFloat(etFirstValue.getText().toString());

            

                secondValue = Float.parseFloat(etSecondValue.getText().toString());
              tvAnswer.setText("Ans = " + ans);
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter the Values First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            ans = firstValue + secondValue;

            tvAnswer.setText("Ans = " + ans);

        }

        });
```

I have solved this on my own.
Now it is not crashing just giving a warning message "Enter the values First"
Thanks to all for giving your precious time.

Answer (score 0):

Just Do Like This

First Convert Your Values To String And Then Do This:

```
if(value1.matches("")){
    Toast(context, "Please Fill First Value", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
else if(value2.matches("")){
    Toast(context, "Please Fill First Value", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
else{
    //Continue With Your Code
    //Do Calculations Or Anything
}
```

**Note:** Change Value1, Value2 With Your Own Values Which Came From EditText

Comment: Is This Answer Working If Yes Upvote My Answer And Tick It

Comment: return also showing error because i have declared initially void

Answer (score 0):

```
    Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override

    public void onClick(View v) {

        float firstValue=null , secondValue=null, ans=0; //initialise the value here
        firstValue = Float.parseFloat( etFirstValue.getText().toString());

        secondValue = Float.parseFloat( etSecondValue.getText().toString());
        if(firstValue==null&&secondvValue==null)
        {
           
            tvAnswer.setText("Ans = " + ans);

         } else{
       ans = firstValue + secondValue;
       tvAnswer.setText("Ans = " + ans);

       }
        
    }

});
```

If the above doesnt work initialise all above value to zero instead of null.

Comment: how to write this show me for add button what to write where to write

Comment: try the new case and if this dont work upload your logcat.

Comment: Upload your logcat

Comment: how it is continuously moving

Comment: disconnect your phone or emulator then check for the error

Comment: disconnected, then also showing error, in the initialization, and in the if condition

Comment: Please add line here in comment where the error is being generated.

Comment: float firstValue=""

Comment: String cannot be converted into float

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake from my side.Just check my new answer.

Comment: I edited your answer.Hope so that worked fine.